# How to run ResGen with Build Events in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resgen

I need to run ResGen before building a project.
In project Properties dialog box, I set up the ResGen, but I go the error `Error    524 The command "ResGen /compile tclscript.txt" exited with code 9009.`.

What's wrong? How can I run ResGen in VS1010?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To see the full error, look at the build output window.  It'll probably say:

> 'resgen.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

ResGen is not in the path environment variable, so you can either put it in or just reference ResGen with an absolute reference:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\resgen.exe"

On my system it's this, however, you may have to search for it on your system.

Comment: This solution does not work on different computers, sometime the resgen is in program files, sometime in program files x86. furthermore different computers accross our team have different version of SDK installed.